# CSS non-standard "ZOOM" property

Tags: css

I have a css file with a class with zoom: 1.

I get the following error on the browser console.

This page uses the non-standard "zoom" property. Instead, you can use calc (), or "transform" together with "transform-origin: 0 0".

How do you convert the property from zoom to transform or calc?
ThankYou

Comment: try to use `transform: scale(1) ` instead of `zoom: 1`

Comment: `zoom: 1` is a popular CSS property, so its possibly coming from a 3rd-party package.

Comment: My concern with this, in my case the css is Bootstrap 3, and by the mere fact it is there tells me that Bootstrap does not care.

Answer (score 11):

You can find a description and recommendation [on the MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom):

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

**recommendation:**

> The non-standard `zoom` CSS property can be used to control the magnification level of an element. `transform: scale()` should be used instead of this property, if possible. However, unlike CSS Transforms, `zoom` affects the layout size of the element.

**demo:**

```css
div.t1 {
  zoom: 0.5;
}
div.t2 {
  transform:scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="t1">Hello World</div>
<div class="t2">Hello World</div>
```