# hide specific warnings in console log

Tags: javascript, console.log

After checking most of the forums in stackoverflow i could not fine a proper solution.
I'm trying to hide the following warning from the console log:

```
This page uses the non standard property “zoom”. Consider using calc() in the relevant property values, or using “transform” along with “transform-origin: 0 0”.
```

i found the following script with works exept warnings messages:

```
(function () {
    var method;
    var noop = function noop() { };
    var methods = [
    'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
    'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
    'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
    'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];
    var length = methods.length;
    var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

    while (length--) {
        method = methods[length];
        console[method] = noop;
    }
}());
```

Thank you for your support and suggetions

Comment: Why not fix the browser warning you are getting from the CSS of your page?

Comment: Why does it matter if there is a warning in the console?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59477050/css-non-standard-zoom-property

Comment: There is no way to remove a specific line from the console. the only solutions are: delete the entire console once the page loads or correct what generates the warning, window.onload = () => {console.clear()}

Comment: @epaccarello, thank you for the feedback. unfortunately there is not way to fix it, is just a warning but does not impact the code or page it selfs